# Turn dictionary-like string into table in Postgre

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, dictionary

I have a dictionary-like string like this:

> {100: {1:500000, 2: 600000}, 200: {1:700000, 2: 800000}, 300: {1:
> 900000, 2: 1000000}}

Note  that the path level is always fixed, but the number of key-value pairs is not.

I want to convert it into a table like this:

```
column 1 | column 2 | column 3
--------------------------------
100      | 1        | 500000
100      | 2        | 600000
200      | 1        | 700000
200      | 2        | 800000
300      | 1        | 900000
300      | 2        | 1000000
```

I've tried using regular expression (`select regexp_split_to_table(string, '[{}:, ]+') from ...`) and get rows of number, but to convert these rows into a table creates another problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the dictionary-like string into a valid JSON using `REGEXP_REPLACE` then apply [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in two levels to get the expected output :

```
SELECT n1.key as column_1, n2.key as column_2, n2.value as column_3
FROM mytable t, jsonb_each(REGEXP_REPLACE(jsoncol, '([0-9]+):', '"\1":', 'g')::jsonb) n1,
                jsonb_each(n1.value) n2
```

Result :

```
column_1    column_2    column_3
100         1           500000
100         2           600000
200         1           700000
200         2           800000
300         1           900000
300         2           1000000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2TvCjQJV)

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried using regexp_replace but it always replaced only the first occurence, so I thought it was not the right tool. However, the issue is with me rather than the tool. Again, thank you!